# Disallow hyphens in e-mail

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I have a regex for e-mail validation which is constructed as following:

```
const emailRegexp = /[a-z0-9._%+]+@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,10}){1,2}$/;
```

Examples:

aaa@aaa-aaa.com  - for this e-mail, validation works and it blocks the users from submiting the form
aa-aa@aaa.com - for this e-mail, validation doesn't work.

How to disallow all hyphens in this particular "emailRegexp" variable?

Comment: Prepend the pattern with `^`

Comment: But...why do you want to [disallow valid emails](https://www.reddit.com/r/softwaregore/comments/7pwbdj/my_email_address_has_a_hyphen_in_it/)? `coca-cola.com` is a real domain that exists.

Comment: It's probably worth noting.... **A valid email address *can* contain a hyphen**. *Any* attempt to validate email addresses with regex is flawed (including the ridiculous 1000+ character"RFC compliant" regexes you'll find online); my advice has always been to use the loosest regex possible (e.g. `^[^@]+@[^@]+$`) and then - if you really need to - ensure that the address is truly valid by sending them a **validation email** (with a confirmation link)

Comment: @TomLord indeed. The problem is that even if you somehow figure out that the email is *valid* as per the specs, that doesn't mean *it exists*. A user signing up with a non-existent email is a way worse problem than them signing up with an email that contains a hyphen, or an apostrophe, or a plus sign, or everything else a lot of developers deem "unworthy" to be in an email. If you want their email, it's to *contact them*, so the only validation that matters is "can you contact the user via this email".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a '^' at the start of the pattern, this asserts the position at the start of the string.

`^[a-z0-9._%+]+@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,10}){1,2}$`